# Android How to send text and images or any object using intent?

Tags: android, image, text, android-intent, share

I know it's possible to share a text message with `ACTION_SEND` by specifying `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. Same approach works for images - `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`.

But how can I add both text and image to the same intent?

Comment: question, would a content provider not be able to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can send text and image via intent like

If you are sending **using Intent ACTION** then,

To send only one data either text or stream use,

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

To send more then one data at a time use,

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);`

---

Normally to send from one specific Activity to any another specific activity,

**Send**

```
Bitmap bmp = "Your Bitmap";
String txt = "Text";
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondFile.class);
intent.putExtra("Text",txt);
intent.putExtra("Img",bmp);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receive**

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
String txt = intent.getStringExtra("Text");
Bitmap bmp = intent.getParcelableExtra("Img");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add as many extras as you want to the same `Intent` :

```
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imgUri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
```

I hope I didn't get your question wrong.