# How to share a contact programatically in android

Tags: java, android, share, contacts, contactscontract

I am presently working on a contact app and i have been searching for a while to share a contact programatically in android. I didn't know in which format i should send the contact to other device. If i am sending as text, how it will be processed into contactscontract Db in receivers device? Can you please suggest me how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the `VCard` handle for the contact (using `ContactsContract` API: `Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI`), and then send it using the `ACTION_SEND` intent.

```
String lookupKey = <the contact's lookup key>;
Uri vcardUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareUri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Bob Dylan"); // put the name of the contact here
startActivity(intent);
```

See more about it here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_VCARD_URI

**UPDATE**

to answer a deleted question by @Abhay Maniyar - to get the lookupKey from a contactId:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY }, Contacts._ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    String lookupKey = cur.getString(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you asking how to share it to something like whatsapps you could try sending it and an intent.

You can send plain text like this:

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

See **[Share image and text through Whatsapp or Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077338/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp-or-facebook)** for more details.

If you want to go further then that, I suggest you take a look at the thirds party development docs like for **[WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)**

Also more general information can be found on **[this page of Android](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)**

**[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType)** is an overview of what you can send in an intent.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond de la Croix ! I ll try this out!

Comment: Goodluck :) I just added another reference site from android, which shows all the send types, which should be helpful aswell

Answer (score 0):

> Use following Code to share your contact, get Contact Name and LookupKey from contact cursor

```
private void shareContact() {
    //lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    String lookupKey2 = lookupKey;
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey2);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri );
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, contactName); // put the name of the contact here
    startActivity(intent);
}
```