# Absolute URI to insert a Contact

Tags: android

I was wondering if I could provide a link to be followed by a web browser (most specifically in a QRCODE) to insert a contact with the contact data already filled. I tried content://com.android.contacts in my mobile firefox but it crashed. I also couldn't find any absolute URI for this in the Android documentation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with QR code, another phone should always have program which can parse QR code information and call system method to add contact.
But in Android you can programmatically share contact.
This link can be helpful: [How to share a contact programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505718/how-to-share-a-contact-programatically-in-android)

Comment: Humm this is interesting so if I provide a link to a vcard could android handle it?

Comment: I tried it and it opened the Contacts app indeed. But I got an error 'Couldn't import vCard, The format isn't supported":

I tried with:


BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Ceolin;Renato;;;
FN:Renato Ceolin
EMAIL:renato.ceolin@renatoceolin.com
END:VCARD

Comment: Try to do some research about vCard formats and check what it is sent and came in appropriate format

Comment: Worked for vCard v3.0, not for v4 tough. But that's what I needed, thank you