# Android Studio: Combine Image and Text of Post to share on Whatsapp?

Tags: android, image, share, whatsapp

In my project sharing only text and if only image in post not sharing anything.. what i need to do?
Android Studio 3: Combine Image and Text of Post to share on Whatsapp?

Below is the function of implementation.

```
public void postShare(Item item) {

    String shareText = "";

    if (item.getPost().length() > 0) {

        shareText = item.getPost();

    } else {

        if (item.getImgUrl() == null || item.getImgUrl().length() == 0) {

            shareText = item.getLink();
        }
    }


    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, (String) context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);

    if ((item.getImgUrl().length() > 0) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        ImageView image;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = App.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        image = new ImageView(context);

        if (imageLoader == null) {

            imageLoader = App.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        }

        imageLoader.get(item.getImgUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(image, R.drawable.profile_default_photo, R.drawable.profile_default_photo));

        Drawable mDrawable = image.getDrawable();
        Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "Image Description", null);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    }

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share post"));
}
```

Comment: duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077338/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp-or-facebook

Comment: what is duplicate in this?