# How do I share image and text together in WhatsApp

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapp

I have a share feature which should share both image and text together. I am doing it as shown below

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file)

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
intent.type = "*/*"

if (etShareMessage.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etShareMessage.text)
}

val title = resources.getString(R.string.screenshot_share_with)

val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title)

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(activity?.packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser)
} else {
    ToastUtils.showToast(context,getString(R.string.screenshot_sorry_no_apps_to_share))
    dismiss()
}
```

It works fine for [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) and [Hike](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsb.hike). But [WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=WhatsApp+Messenger&c=apps) shows only the image. I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077338/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp-or-facebook) post and few other links. But no luck. I can see that [Amazon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping) app and [Loco](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.showtimeapp) app are able to do this.

Why isn't WhatsApp taking text from the above intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of trial and error, I found that the way we pass text via Intent.EXTRA_TEXT matters for WhatsApp!!

I just changed

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etShareMessage.text)
```

to

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etShareMessage.text.toString())
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR TEXT");
                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bm, "", null);
                    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
```

By this method we can share image to whatsapp the image is in an imageView

Comment: Tried this by placing my file in the external directory as my file is inside cache directory. But no luck.

Comment: And add the necessary permissions. And runtime permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
```

instead of:

```
Intent.ACTION_SEND
```

Comment: No difference with this